# How do I connect widget to my background service which is used to play music?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm trying to build a basic music player but right now I'm stuck at making widget for it. Can someone tell me how do I connect widget to the background service? I'm using MediaBrowser,MediaController on the client side and MediaBrowserService,MediaSession in the background service.
So, to create a instance of MediaController, I require activity which isn't available in widget class if I'm not wrong and if I try to bind widget class to service using bindService and returning an instance of the background service class method I'm getting error (which is resolved once I comment the onBind method in the service)

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

AppWidgetProvider is a *BroadcastReceiver* on steroids. But you can't bind to service from BroadcastReceivers (That was done because *BroadcastReceiver* is lightweight component that have shot livetime (10 seconds)). In your case best way to communicate with music service is use broadcasts (pending intents).